# Seamless (RSE) Remote Projects in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, remote-access

I've been trying - without much success - to make Eclipse (for C/C++, but that should be irrelevant) play nicely with remote projects. It would make my life at work much easier if I can set things in the following way:

- Run Eclipse from my local Windows machine
- Connect (through Eclipse) to the remote Linux development box
- Create an Eclipse project from files and directories already created on the remote box
- Configure project dependencies and symbols using files and directories from the remote box
- Building and running the project in Eclipse is not needed - since this is done with a million makefiles, it's easier for me to just SSH into the box and build from command line. I just need Eclipse to recognize included resources

I tried setting this up with Remote System Explorer (RSE), but couldn't quite get it to work. I can create a connection to the remote box, browse its files, and even convert certain directories to Remote Projects. Once the remote project is created, however, it's useless to me - Eclipse underlines everything that's not a C/C++ keyword, saying it doesn't recognize it (even #include statements of system libraries); equally important, it doesn't allow me to add remote resources to the Paths & Symbols of the project.

Am I missing something here, or RSE just not capable of doing what I need it to?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you're missing something here. I already faced a similar problem when creating/editing remote projects. As far as I can judge, this must be due to the C/C++ indexer not working correctly for remote projects. One action to make Eclipse recognize the `#include`s is to close and reopen the project through the Project Explorer View. If this doesn't help, try highlighting the `#include` statement and press F3. Opening the included file seems to trigger the indexer to update the index (although this *should* also be possible by right-clicking the project and selecting the Rebuild Index function; but this didn't work me). But even after performing these steps, indexing isn't fully functional, e.g., the Call Hierarchy is not working at all (it tells me "File XY is currently not part of the index").

Btw, which protocol do you use for your connection (ssh, ftp, or dstore)? I read some posts that RSE only works seamlessly if the dstore protocol is used. Unfortunately, this wasn't the case for me...